# How to SUM a range in Excel based on CELL/INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I am trying to sum a range in Excel.  I want users to be able to enter a date in one cell.  Then I want to sum a range based on a static starting cell location and the corresponding location based on the date they enter.  For example, if they enter 1/3/2021 for the report date, I want to sum the range between B2 and B4 to get $14.  I have the following formula which gives me an error.  Any ideas on how to get this formula to work as expected?  Thanks for your help!

=SUM(B2:CELL("address",INDEX(A2:B63,MATCH(G1,A2:A63,1),2)))

[image]

[image]

| Date | Sales | Misc Column | Misc Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | $3 | Report Date | 1/4/2021 |
| 1/2/2021 | $6 | Sales Total Formula | =SUM(B2:CELL("address",INDEX(A2:B5,MATCH(D2,A1:A5,1)2))) |
| 1/3/2021 | $5 | Sales Total (expected value) | $21 |
| 1/4/2021 | $7 | Sales Total (actual value) | I get an error |

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are sorted:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<="&D2)
```

[image]

If not:

```
=SUM(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)))
```

[image]